# Maxwell Equations WITHOUT electric monopoles/charges

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, vacuum

I was wondering if Maxwell equations in vacuum would also describe a universe without electric monopoles, but where dipoles etc. are allowed.

\begin{align}
  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} &= 0 \quad & -\nabla \times \mathbf{E} &= \frac{\partial\mathbf B}{\partial t}, \\
  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} &= 0 \quad & \nabla \times \mathbf{B} &=  \frac{\partial\mathbf E}{\partial t}.
\end{align}

Or maybe we have to modify the equations further?

Edit:
In other words is it possible to have electric dipoles etc. given the fact that Maxwell equations are the ones in the vacuum?

Comment: I don't understand the question: The absence of electric monopoles is just $\rho = 0$ - why would you need to "modify" anything?

Comment: I'm just asking to be sure, so they should be like I said exactly like the vacuum equations, right? (so $\rho$ and J equals to 0)

Comment: I do not understand what possible difference there is between "vacuum" and "no electric monopoles"

Comment: With "vacuum" I refer to "no particles", with "no electric monopoles" I refer to the possible presence of charges, but only in pairs that cancel each other (so it's not "vacuum" since particles are present)

Comment: @ACuriousMind the question is asking whether it's possible to have electric dipoles without monopoles, just like we have magnetic dipoles but no monopoles.